# Protractor Custom Locator is getting failed to locate the element

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, protractor

In our project, the automation team will include custom attribute 'lid' to the element where ever we cannot identify the element uniquely.

I created a custom locator method to detect the element using custom attribute 'lid'. It is below:

```
   by.addLocator('lid', function(value, parentElement) 
    { 
    parentElement = parentElement || document; 
     var nodes = parentElement.querySelectorAll('lid'); 

     return Array.prototype.filter.call(nodes, function(node) 
     { 
         return (node.getAttribute('lid') === value); 
     }); 
   });
```

Here the html code of the page

```
 <div class="col-sm-8 cbx">
                        <p class="ng-binding"><input type="radio" ng-model="theme"
 lid="create-user-them-radio1" ng-value="1" ng-click="user.theme = -1" class="ng-
pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty" name="1194" value="1"> Use the default
 for this domain</p>
                        <p class="litetext ng-binding">Following options override 
the domain's default value</p>
                        <p class="ng-binding"><input type="radio" ng-model="theme"
 lid="create-user-them-radio2" ng-value="2" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-
valid ng-not-empty" name="1195" value="2"> Select theme for the user</p>
 </div>
```

I want to use 'lid' attribute and locate the element and wrote the above method to work with any attribute and value.

I call the method from the test file as below:

```
element(by.lid("create-user-them-radio1")).click();
```

I am getting '**No element found using locator: by.lid("create-user-theme-radio1")**'

Need help to resolve the issue.

Comment: Does the equivalent xpath locator identify the element successfully? It should be something like `element(by.xpath(".//li[@ng-if="$select.open"]"));`

Comment: have you tried by css yet? element(by.css('[ng-if="$select.open"]'));

Comment: You need to escape special characters and you should do it twice. so you have `$select\\.open` Possibly you'll need to escape `$` character also

Comment: Thanks all, in our project xpaths are not supposed to be used. instead of that, we are creating custom Locators to use. In this example, I gave it as ng-if but many other places no unique attributes, that places adding a custom attribute and use through the customLocator method and hence thought of creating a generic method.

Comment: Hi All, I updated my question as more specific, can please check and suggest some solution to this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to find the correct solution for this and the solution is as below:

```
by.addLocator('lid', function(value, parentElement) {
        var nodes;

        if(parentElement)
            nodes =  parentElement.querySelectorAll();
        else
            nodes = document.querySelectorAll('body *');


        return Array.prototype.filter.call(nodes, function(node) {
            if( node.hasAttribute("lid") && node.getAttribute('lid') === value)
                return node;
        });
    });
```

querySelectorAll() needs to give the input as 'tag', if no parentElement is sent then it queries all the tags under 'body' tag otherwise all elements from the parentElement. After that loop through all the elements and check whether attribute 'lid' exists or not. If exists verify the value, if the value is desired value then it return that element.

Answer (score 0):

why you need to create custom method if you can do the same things by defaults methods

`element(by.xpath('.//li[contains(@ng-if, "$select.open")]')).click();`

PS: if you will run tests on prod mode, then this locator will not work. attributes like ng-%blabla% embedded only in dev mode.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your time and I updated the question, please check and provide the solution. Actually, i want to create a custom locator method as we are adding new locator 'lid' to the application wherever cannot identify the element uniquely and either css or xpath are the options left.